# Error in the coding of the characters in reading a PDF

Tags: python, pdf, pypdf

I need to read [this PDF](http://www.bepid.ifce.edu.br/resultado_prova_selecao.pdf).

I am using the following code:

```
from PyPDF2 import PdfFileReader

f = open('myfile.pdf', 'rb')
reader = PdfFileReader(f)
content = reader.getPage(0).extractText()
f.close()
content = ' '.join(content.replace('\xa0', ' ').strip().split())

print(content)
```

However, the encoding is incorrect, it prints:

```
Resultado da Prova de Sele“‰o do...
```

But I expected

```
Resultado da Prova de Seleção do...
```

How to solve it?

I'm using Python 3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The PyPDF2 [extractTest method](https://github.com/mstamy2/PyPDF2/blob/master/PyPDF2/pdf.py) returns UniCode. So you many need to just explicitly encode it. For example, explicitly encoding the Unicode into UTF-8.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
correct = u'Resultado da Prova de Seleção do...'
print(correct.encode(encoding='utf-8'))
```

You're on Python 3, so you have Unicode under the hood, and Python 3 defaults to UTF-8. But I wonder if you need to specify a different encoding based on your [locale](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/locale.html).

```
# Show installed locales
import locale
from pprint import pprint
pprint(locale.locale_alias)
```

If that's not the quick fix, since you're getting Unicode back from PyPDF, you could take a look at the code points for those two characters. It's possible that PyPDF wasn't able to determine the correct encoding and gave you the wrong characters.

For example, a quick and dirty comparison of the good and bad strings you posted:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
# Python 3.4
incorrect = 'Resultado da Prova de Sele“‰o do'
correct = 'Resultado da Prova de Seleção do...'

print("Incorrect String")
print("CHAR{}UNI".format(' ' * 20))
print("-" * 50)
for char in incorrect:
    print(
        '{}{}{}'.format(
            char.encode(encoding='utf-8'),
            ' ' * 20,  # Hack; Byte objects don't have __format__
            ord(char)
        )
    )

print("\n" * 2)

print("Correct String")
print("CHAR{}UNI".format(' ' * 20))
print("-" * 50)
for char in correct:
    print(
        '{}{}{}'.format(
            char.encode(encoding='utf-8'),
            ' ' * 20,  # Hack; Byte objects don't have __format__
            ord(char)
        )
    )
```

Relevant Output:

> b'\xe2\x80\x9c'                    8220
> b'\xe2\x80\xb0'                    8240
>
> b'\xc3\xa7'                    231
> b'\xc3\xa3'                    227

If you're getting code point [231](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/e7/index.htm), (`>>>hex(231)  # '0xe7`) then you're getting back bad data back from PyPDF.

Comment: Really, the problem is in PyPDF. As I can not solve the problem, [I sent a message on GitHub](https://github.com/mstamy2/PyPDF2/issues/235)

Answer (score 0):

what i have tried is to replace specific " ' " unicode with "’" which solves this issue. Please let me know if u still failed to generate pdf with this approach.

```
text = text.replace("'", "’")
```